# How can I offline install tkinter for python3.11?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tkinter, rhel

In this case I'm having problems with Tkinter, although it is in the installed libraries/packages from python 3.11 installation, It seems I can't use it.

Whenever I try import tkinter it gives me the following error:

> No module named '_tkinter'

My problem is that I'm using an **offline linux RHEL 8**, so I can't use sudo yum install python3-tk.

What could I do to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You can download the package using an online machine and copy the package to the RHEL 8.

Comment: @acw1668 hi! thank you very much, could you tell me which file or files should I copy? thanks!

Comment: If you have the CD/DVD of RHEL 8, you can just copy the package file from it.

Comment: I think the file you need is [python3.11-tkinter-3.11.2-2.el8.x86_64.rpm](https://centos.pkgs.org/8-stream/centos-powertools-x86_64/python3.11-tkinter-3.11.2-2.el8.x86_64.rpm.html).